# CSS bug with drop down Menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation

When i hover over the Gallery its displays the sub menu list next to each other but i wnat the sub 1 and 2 display below each other so its a dropdown. And how could i improve this code and is ther any cod that i dont need in it.

Here is the picture:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="menu_wrapper">
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_parent">Gallery</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_parent">Plants</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_parent">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="last">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>     

    </div> <!-- end of menu -->
</div><!-- end of menu_wrapper -->
```

CSS

```
    /*
CSS
*/
#menu_wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    background: url(menu_bar.jpg) no-repeat center top;
}

#menu {
    width: 900px;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url(menu_bar.jpg) no-repeat center top; 
}

#menu ul {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 30px 0 0 150px;
    list-style: none;
}

#menu ul li {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline;
}

#menu ul li a {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 115px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #eee901; 
    font-weight: bold;
    outline: none;
    background: url(menu_item.png) no-repeat;
}

#menu li a:hover, #menu li .current {
    color: #FFF;
}

#menu ul ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
}
#nav ul ul li {
    display:block;
}

#menu ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
#menu ul li:hover ul li{
    style:none;
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for specific code problems. If you also want help reviewing the quality of your code, consider CodeReview.StackExchange for that, instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS to get the behaviour you're looking for is almost correct - it just seems that you've written the wrong id for one of your CSS selectors.

Where you have:

```
#nav ul ul li {
    display:block;
}
```

You should have:

```
#menu ul ul li {
    display:block;
}
```

This style overrides the `display:inline` you set elsewhere in your CSS, and causes the submenu items to stack. Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yZMFL/) to demonstrate. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

(With regards to code improvements...well, you don't seem to need to specify `float:left` on your `<ul>` elements. Although what you need and don't need can vary depending on the broader context of your website.)

Comment: And how can i make the dropdown list display exact under it because the list is a little shifted toward right and thanks again

Comment: Sure, that's just a matter of removing the fixed width on the submenu anchor tag. `#menu ul ul li a{ width:auto; }` resolves that issue in this case.

Comment: Okay, I changed a slew of styles and altered the way the dropdown is positioned. To summarize: Removed all `float:left` on `<ul>`, removed `position:relative` on `<a>`, added `position:relative` to `<li>`, and altered the positioning of the submenu so it uses `left/top` rather than `padding` to be positioned. The submenu items are now centered in a dropdown below the main menu item. http://jsfiddle.net/yZMFL/2/

Comment: Hmm, can you mock up a JSFiddle and/or provide a screenshot for that? It's a bit difficult to troubleshoot just by that description.

Comment: Right ah, how does it look right now though? I'm just not sure what kind of bug you're looking at.

Comment: Do you just mean that the dropdown doesn't appear? That would be because you didn't add the HTML in for it yet. http://jsfiddle.net/ut9R9/3/

Comment: The background color overlays the corner of the menu wrapper. [Picture](http://postimg.org/image/ux690djin/)

Comment: Oh, that issue is just because the container is too small. Rather than 900px, use `#site_title_bar { width:1000px; }`, the size of your image. http://jsfiddle.net/ut9R9/5/

Comment: Although, that may not be it. I'm not seeing exactly the problem you're indicating - what browser are you using?

Comment: Odd, it looks fine for me in Chrome 28. http://postimg.org/image/6mku5rrib/ (Don't trust Dreamweaver's live preview though, it can be terribly inaccurate.)